# Is it possible to pass a Stream as ulong

Tags: c#

I got an Interface method with an `ulong` out parameter.

```
int ReadStream(int channelID, out ulong handle, int timeout)
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a `MemoryStream` and pass a handle to this stream as out parameter.

like this, but I don't know if it is possible and if it is, how do I get a pointer to my stream and convert it to ulong? I tried this:

```
public override int ReadStream(int channelID, out ulong handle, int timeout)
{

  Stream localStream = new MemoryStream();

  GCHandle localHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(localStream, GCHandleType.Pinned);
  IntPtr pointer = localHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();


  handle = pointer;
  return kSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that kSuccess is never declared?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno kSuccess is a global constant, what does it matter?

Comment: Wouldn't the localStream be out of scope and collected anyway?

Comment: Why don't you just make the stream as a global variable to ensure that it won't be collected?

Comment: @sam I really don't know, thats why I'm asking is it even possible and if so, how is it done.

Comment: @Fildor its an interface method, I cannot change the signature.

Comment: @Fildor he might be implementing some interface

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Overread that part.

Comment: Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data. on the `GCHandle.Alloc(localStream, GCHandleType.Pinned);`  [check also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549992/514449)

Comment: You could have a static dictionary in which the key is the ulong handle and the value the stream. This way we are sure your stream won't be collected. To get a pointer to the stream (to be used as key) look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37016762/711061