# Non Primitive/Blittable exception (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, marshalling, unmanaged

First of all I'm not quite familiar with marshalling and dealing with unmanaged resources. 
I was migrating a project  that was compiled and ran with mono and Framework v4.6.1. Basically what I had to do was only change the target framework, yet one thing that made everything stop working was trying to Pin an object into memory with `GCHandle.Alloc`. That threw an exception stating that
`Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.`

What I find weird is that this allegedly (I take the word of the owner when [he says that it runs successfully](https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-csharp#test-status)) this works when running with Mono. is there any difference on how .NET core and Mono treat memory ?

The exception is thrown when I do the following:

```
private ws2811_t _ws2811;
private GCHandle _ws2811Handle;

public WS281x(Settings settings)
{
    _ws2811 = new ws2811_t();
    //Pin the object in memory. Otherwise GC will probably move the object to another memory location.
    //This would cause errors because the native library has a pointer on the memory location of the object.
    _ws2811Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_ws2811, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

Here's the Object that I'm trying to pin:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct ws2811_t
{
    public long render_wait_time;
    public IntPtr device;
    public IntPtr rpi_hw;
    public uint freq;
    public int dmanum;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = PInvoke.RPI_PWM_CHANNELS)]
    public ws2811_channel_t[] channel;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct ws2811_channel_t
{
    public int gpionum;
    public int invert;
    public int count;
    public int strip_type;
    public IntPtr leds;
    public byte brightness;
    public byte wshift;
    public byte rshift;
    public byte gshift;
    public byte bshift;
    public IntPtr gamma;
}
```

}

I've looked on both mono [Blittable types](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#blittable-types) and [dotnet blittable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) but I'm not familiar with that
Is this a possible bug, or simply misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (in the body of the question itself, not in a link).

Comment: My bad, didn't want to extend it much. I'll edit it.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544818/non-blittable-error-on-a-blittable-type help?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30133), the code was working on mono because mono had a bug. In my case, since my array only had 2 positions, I've created 2 fields and the problem was solved